# What to do if a post in the HIQ has already been edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, help-improvement

I was browsing the Help and Improvement queue, but I found that more than half of what I saw had already been edited by somebody else and looked fine.

Now, this is great, where is the problem?

The problem is, I cannot indicate that I think it's fine already. I only have the option to "edit" or "skip". But I want to do neither. I want to indicate that there is nothing left to do, it looks fine.

What am I supposed to do? Right now, I skipped them, because I don't think making fake edits is a great solution. But skipping is not the signal I want to send. To me, skipping is something I do when the question is out of my comfort zone and somebody else should edit it, not when it's good already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to indicate that there is nothing left to do, it looks fine.

Then skip it; let someone else take a shot at it. If *no one* thinks there's room for improvement, it'll quietly drop out of the queue on its own.

Posts end up in the queue when several people think they needed work. Maybe they're all wrong, but it's also possible there's some deficiency you're not seeing. Don't stress about it; if you don't see anything to do, skip and try another one.

Comment: The point is that I see that it already *has been done*. If skipping is the preferred solution, I will do so.

Comment: @nvoigt this answer means what **you** see has *already done* is not necessarily *everything that could be done* to improve it, so he advises you to skip it and let someone else have another look at it

Comment: @Eregrith so where is the difference then between 500 people skipping because it looks ok now and 500 people skipping thinking "god, that's horrible, but not my tag"?

Comment: @nvoigt None, indeed.

Comment: I know it is the way HIQ works now and that there are other problems in it (questions editable only by OP). But this is really almost as bothering because the result is the same : queue is full of post that we can only skip ! So we browse the queue, keep on skipping because posts are either already ok, or need OP intervention, and finally give up.