# Why do edited questions appear in the Help and Improvement Queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, help-improvement

While reviewing in the "Help and Improvement" queue I came across many questions that already had been edited by other users, and they still appear in review queue. As I think once a question has been edited they should be removed from the queue, but they still appear.

The "Skip" button is probably the best option in these cases, but why should they increase the queue size when the question has already been fixed?

Comment: There's always room for improvement.

Comment: @CinCout but there are still lot of questions which still need improvement. So priority should be given to them instead of ones that are corrected to an extent.

Comment: *"The Skip button is probably the best option in these cases"* No, it is not. Use "Skip" if you are unsure. If the edits that were made are sufficient, and the post does not need further edits, then click "Looks OK" (or whatever they've labeled the button).

Comment: @CodyGray there are only 2 buttons `Skip` and `edit`

Comment: Oh, um, alright then. How do they decide when these posts should be removed from the queue? Surely it's not after they've been hot-potatoed by a certain number of users...

Comment: That's what I want to know

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 triage queue has more option than Help and Improvement queue so I don't think that is going to help. Moreover my question is not about when to use which option while reviewing, it is about why edited question still appear in queue after they are already edited

Comment: @VivekMishra Doh! Clicked on the wrong duplicate - fixed. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: @CodyGray: That's [exactly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290812) how H&I dequeues. (That, or time; Shog wasn't real clear.)

Answer (score 1):

Just because a post has been edited once doesn't mean it's now a great post.  Lots of people edit bad posts to fix or change one small thing, leaving lots of other problems.  The real overhaul edits (that the queue is specifically designed to encourage) are rare, and it's certainly not safe to assume that just because a bad post was edited, that it was such a complete overhaul of an edit.

Comment: But that post can be edited more accurately by the users of the question's tag and moreover what I think that clearing queue should be the priority.

Comment: @VivekMishra I'm not so sure that it could be better edited by other users, but even so, many of them *won't* make comprehensive edits.  Just spend some time looking through edited posts and seeing how much has changed.   In the vast majority of edits, it's only a small improvement, and it's not turning a bad post into a great one.  Most people just don't take the time to fix *all* of the problems, so assuming that they have is almost always going to be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: NO, clearing the queue is *not* the priority.  The priority is improving the content of the site.  Removing posts from the queue that haven't actually been improved just to see a smaller queue *is counter productive*.  The purpose of the queue is to point people able and willing to make significant improving edits to posts to posts that need improving.  Clearing the queue when we know there are posts that could use said attention is *inhibiting the ability of the queue to do its job*.  If you're only interested in clearing queues and not actually improving posts, you shouldn't be reviewing.

Comment: Ok I agree with that but shouldn't there be a `Looks Ok` button when the edited post looks ok?

Comment: @VivekMishra Perhaps.  If you proposed that it would be radically different than suggesting every edit kicks a post out of the queue.  You'd still need to support the position that such an option is actually needed though.

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean